# Numeric Extensions.Clamp(double, double, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level in xamarin forms class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on adding pitch to zoom into my xamarin forms content page and I'm using [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithGestures/PinchGesture/PinchGesture) example and i'm getting this error  upon running the app on my phone:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0122  'NumericExtensions.Clamp(double, double, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level   AppName.Forms   C:\TFSMOBILE\AppName.NETStandard\AppName.Forms\Pages\PinchToZoomContainer.cs    55  Active

here's the code for the PinchToZoomContainer:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName.Forms.Pages
{
    public class PinchToZoomContainer : ContentView
    {
        double currentScale = 1;
        double startScale = 1;
        double xOffset = 0;
        double yOffset = 0;

        public PinchToZoomContainer()
        {
            var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
            pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
        }

        void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
                // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the X pixel coordinate.
                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
                //error 1:
                Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                //error 2:
                Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                // Apply scale factor
                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is your `DoubleExtensions.Clamp` extension method assigned as `public`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That project you referenced on GitHub is using its own `Clamp` function and not the internal Forms-based one and due to the error I would assume you are missing this class:

```
using System;

namespace PinchGesture
{
    public static class DoubleExtensions
    {
        public static double Clamp (this double self, double min, double max)
        {
            return Math.Min (max, Math.Max (self, min));
        }
    }
}
```

Re: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/290d8947432fef55852bf381dcaec393d638f150/WorkingWithGestures/PinchGesture/PinchGesture/Extensions/DoubleExtensions.cs

Comment: D'oh I totally overlooked that!

Answer (score 2):

in the current release version of Xamarin Forms, NumericExtensions is internal.  It will be changed to public in a future release.

In the meantime, you can easily implement [Clamp](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/NumericExtensions.cs) yourself

```
return Math.Min(max, Math.Max(value, min));
```